# Kill Grunt process in Git post-receive hook

Tags: linux, git, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, git-post-receive

S/O,

I've been trying to iron out auto-deployment for a web app I'm developing and I've set up a git post-receive hook that handles artisan migration, composer update, npm update, and then runs Grunt to copy, uglify, etc. all my necessary assets.

My Grunt task executes grunt-contrib-watch after everything is complete, for the sake of local development. Now, I don't want to go through the hassle of setting up separate Gruntfiles for dev & staging, so in my post-receive, I'm executing Gruntfile.js and then attempting to kill the process (so watch doesn't keep running on the staging server).

The last two lines of my post-receive look like this:

```
grunt --gruntfile /dir/dir/Gruntfile.js >> log.txt
pkill grunt -e >> log.txt
```

However, this doesn't seem to be killing the process as `ps aux | grep grunt` still returns an active process and no relevant output is appended to my `log.txt` file.

Any ideas here would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured this out in two ways:

The first way was to append an & at the end of the grunt call, handing back over control of the CLI to my post-receive script. This worked, but it required me to throw a sleep in there before the pkill to ensure the grunt task was done before it killed the process. Not the kind of ambiguous control I wanted to have over this task.

So, I went on to figure out how to set up a separate task in my Gruntfile for staging. This was easier and more practical than I initially expected.

With a separate task registered that didn't execute a watch at the end, all I had to do was execute grunt like this:

```
grunt --gruntfile /dir/dir/Gruntfile.js staging >> log.txt
```

Where `staging` is the name of the task I registered in grunt. As a note, Grunt will only execute the `default` task when run without this extra parameter, so it still works exactly as I want it to locally without any changes to my workflow :)

Thanks anyways, all. Hope someone finds this answer useful!